# i want select an item from the combo box and open another frame according to the selected item when I click a button

Tags: java, string, if-statement, combobox

I tried this code but it is not working, And there are no errors in the code.In here next means my button.

```
 private void nextActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                     

        String value=(String)select.getSelectedItem();//select is my combo box
        if("image file".equals(value)){

            ImageCrypto im=new ImageCrypto();
            im.setVisible(true);
            this.dispose();

        }else if("text file".equals(value)){
            TextCrypto im=new TextCrypto();
            im.setVisible(true);
            this.dispose();
        }

    }
```

Comment: what does happen and what should happen? always ask yourself if you could answer a question with the given information, before submitting it

Comment: I have mentioned it in the topic

Comment: i want select an item from the combo box and open another frame according to the selected item when I click a button.

Comment: I expect `value` contains number, and `image file` or `text file` is String. Obviously they won't matched.

Comment: oops yeah I corrected it. But still not working

Comment: What have you corrected ?

Comment: That's not what I meant . Check what value you get by using `System.out.println(value)` .

Comment: yeah I checked,It's a String

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I expect `value` contains number, and `image file` or `text file` is `String`. Obviously they won't matched.

You can print out the `value` and check what does the value is. After that only do the comparison.

```
private void nextActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                     

        String value=(String)select.getSelectedItem(); 
        System.out.println(value); // example you get abc
        if("abc".equals(value)){  // change to abc

            ImageCrypto im=new ImageCrypto();
            im.setVisible(true);
            this.dispose();

        }else if("text file".equals(value)){
            TextCrypto im=new TextCrypto();
            im.setVisible(true);
            this.dispose();
        }

    }
```

Comment: Yeah I'll do so. Thank you so much

Comment: I did so.It is a String

Comment: The value is "text file". It means it is a String

Comment: add another else and see does it goes to the else block

Comment: Hey @John Joe I fount the error. The value I have in the combo box is "Image file" But I have used "image file". The reason was the case of the first letter of the word. Now it is working.Thank you so much for your help.

Comment: But just now you get `text file` but `TextCrypto` not getting called ?

Comment: It is.. There are two frames at the moment.One is textCrypto and the other one is ImageCrypto.When I select the appropriate name from the combo box, the related frame loads. And now both are frames are getting called.

Comment: Here, Text file and Image file are the items in the combo box

Comment: I'm glad you fixed it :D